# Why are my objects overlapping on my Swing UI?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

I have created a swing UI in java using a gridbag layout. Here is the code for adding the components;

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth=2;
        this.add(loggedInLabel, c);
       // c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor =GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        this.add(inputCommand, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        this.add(confirmCommandButton, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        this.add(replyField,c);
     //   c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor =GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        this.add(screens,c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=4;
        c.gridwidth=2;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        c.weightx = 0.25;
        c.weighty = 0.25;
       this.add(scrollPane,c);
```

For some reason, the screens object (JComboBox) is overlapping the input command object (JTextField). Does anyone know why? They are meant to be on different x co-ordinates

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue

Answer (score 2):

Analyze your code, first you set gridwidth to 2, this means that all subsequent components have an x grid span of 2, including `inputCommand`:

```
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth=2; //Span 2 columns
    this.add(loggedInLabel, c);
    c.anchor =GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    this.add(inputCommand, c); //inputCommand is two columns wide, cells (0,1)-(1,1)
    .....
    c.anchor =GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    this.add(screens,c); //Screens is also two columns wide, starting from 1 so 
                            //it will partially overlap inputCommand on cell (1,1)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Just one of those oversights. Probably time to take a break

Answer (score 1):

After adding all of the missing lines to your code, I came up with the following GUI.

[image: GUI]

I had to make so many guesses as to what the rest of your code looks like, I have no idea if this matches what you did.

I added an `Insets` instance to separate the components.

Here's the complete runnable code I used.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GirdBagLayout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        JLabel loggedInLabel = new JLabel("Logged in");
        panel.add(loggedInLabel, c);
        // c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        JTextField inputCommand = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(inputCommand, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        JButton confirmCommandButton = new JButton("Confirm Command");
        panel.add(confirmCommandButton, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        JTextField replyField = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(replyField, c);
        // c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        JPanel screens = new JPanel();
        panel.add(screens, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        c.weightx = 0.25;
        c.weighty = 0.25;
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        panel.add(scrollPane, c);
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```